# Validation Multiple Forms and Calculate Values

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm having a bit of trouble when validating the forms. The design of the form was provided to me but I have to write the script to validate the form. When I got to validating the State and everything after, it didn't work. When working on the grand total due, it's suppose to change with the registration fee and everything else but I couldn't make the value show and calculate. Please help. This is a accelerated javascript class and I'm just so used to java.

**I need to do the following:**
When the user changes the number attending the banquet, calculate the total banquet fee, display the amount, and recalculate and display the grand total.

When the user clicks the Register button, verify that the required fields have been completed.  The form should only be submitted when the required fields meet the following criteria:

- First name, Last name, Street, and City may not be blank
- A State must be chosen
- A 5 digit zip code must be entered (Optional - the 5 digit or 9 digit form may be used)
- The email address must contain an "@" sign (Optional - locate and apply a Regular Expression for validating the format of an email address)
- The phone number must be entered using exactly 3 digits for the area code, 3 digit prefix, and a 4 digit exchange

Here is what the form looks like:
https://angel.aacc.edu/AngelUploads/Content/CSI1498752012FA/Misc/Lab5.htm

so far only got this

```
function validateForm()
{
    var valid = false;

    if(document.registration.fname.value == "")
    {
        alert("First name must be entered.");
        return valid;
    }
    else if(document.registration.lname.value ==  "")
    {
        alert("Last name must be entered.");
        return valid;
    }
    else if(document.registration.street.value ==  "")
    {
        alert("Sreet address must be entered.");
        return valid;
    }
    else if(document.registration.city.value ==  "")
    {
        alert("City must be entered.");
        return valid;
    }
    else if(document.registration.zip.value == /(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/)
    {
        alert("Enter a valid zip code.");
        return valid;
    }
}

function calcTotal()
{
    // some code here
}
```

Comment: 1) change to `<form onsubmit="return validateForm()" ...>`
2) add `return valid` to the end of the function

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but when I leave the form blank, it should say "Name must be entered." but its not popping up anything now.

Comment: I think you should keep your lines `valid = false;` and put `return valid;` at the end of your function (outside any `if` statements). That way, all fields are validated and the user will be notified if several fields are blank or invalid. If you `return valid;` inside of every `if` statement, the user will only be notified of the first invalid field. But I guess that preference is up to you. If you want to keep it that way, you should just `return false;` in each `if` statement.

Comment: Ad now you need to return true at the very end

Answer (score 0):

You were missing quite a bit..there is some code below which I think should get you much closer.
A couple of the issues I noticed were, City was looking for != instead of ==, submit button should only return if validation is successful, so instead of

```
onclick="validateForm()"

onclick="return validateForm()"
```

I added a call to CalcTotal to the body of the HTML, so that it is always set to something.

and then I got you started on the sub-total fields, I think you'll need to do some editing there, but hopefully this gets you close enough to finish it up.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration Form</title>
<style>
#main h1 {font-size: 18pt; color: rgb(83,183,51); letter-spacing: 4;
       border-top: 2px solid rgb(83,183,51); font-weight: bold}
#main p {font-size: 9pt;}
#main #intro {text-align: right; font-weight: bold}
span {color: red}

table {font-size: 8pt; width: 510px; padding: 10px;
       border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(83,183,51)}

#lname, #fname, #city, #email, #memberid {width: 198px}
#street {width: 432px}
#zip {width: 88px}
#regFee, #banq, #options, #grandTotal {width: 60px}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

function validateForm()
{

    if(document.registration.fname.value == "")
    {
        alert("First name must be entered.");
        return false;
    }
    else if(document.registration.lname.value ==  "")
    {
        alert("Last name must be entered.");
        return false;
    }
    else if(document.registration.street.value ==  "")
    {
        alert("Street address must be entered.");
        return false;
    }
    else if(document.registration.city.value ==  "")
    {
        alert("City must be entered.");
        return false;
    }
    else if(document.registration.state.value ==  "Choose")
        {
            alert("Please select a state");
            return false;
    }
    else if(document.registration.zip.value == /(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/)
    {
        alert("Enter a valid zip code.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;          
}


function calcMeals()
{
    var mealTotal = 0.00;

    if(document.getElementById("optBreakfast").checked)
        mealTotal = mealTotal + 5.00;
    if(document.getElementById("optLunch").checked)
        mealTotal = mealTotal + 10.00;
    document.getElementById("options").value = mealTotal.toFixed(2);
    calcTotal();
}

function calcBanq()
{
    var banqTotal = 0
    var numGuests = document.getElementById("guest").value;
    if(numGuests > 0)
        document.getElementById("banq").value = (30 * numGuests);
    else
        document.getElementById("banq").value = 0.00;
}

function calcTotal()
{
    var regFee = 125.00;
    var options = document.getElementById("options");
    var banquet = document.getElementById("banq");
    var total = regFee + Number(options.value) + Number(banquet.value);

    document.getElementById("grandTotal").value = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2)
}



</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
<p id="intro">15th Annual JavaScript Conference<br />
   Anne Arundel Community College<br />
   April 26<br />
   Conference Fee: $125
</p>
<h1>Conference Registration Form</h1>

<form id="registration" name="registration" >

<table>
<tr>
   <td><span>*</span>First Name</td>
   <td><input name="fname" id="fname" /></td>
   <td><span>*</span>Last</td>
   <td colspan="3"><input name="lname" id="lname" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td><span>*</span>Street</td>
   <td colspan="5"><input type="text" id="street" name="street" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td><span>*</span>City</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="city" name="city" /></td>
   <td><span>*</span>State</td>
   <td><select id="state" name="state">
              <option value="" selected>Choose</option>
              <option value="AK" >AK</option>
              <option value="AL" >AL</option>
              <option value="AR" >AR</option>
              <option value="AZ" >AZ</option>
              <option value="CA" >CA</option>
              <option value="CO" >CO</option>

              <option value="CT" >CT</option>
              <option value="DC" >DC</option>
              <option value="DE" >DE</option>
              <option value="FL" >FL</option>
              <option value="GA" >GA</option>
              <option value="HI" >HI</option>

              <option value="IA" >IA</option>
              <option value="ID" >ID</option>
              <option value="IL" >IL</option>
              <option value="IN" >IN</option>
              <option value="KS" >KS</option>
              <option value="KY" >KY</option>

              <option value="LA" >LA</option>
              <option value="MA" >MA</option>
              <option value="MD" >MD</option>
              <option value="ME" >ME</option>
              <option value="MI" >MI</option>
              <option value="MN" >MN</option>

              <option value="MO" >MO</option>
              <option value="MS" >MS</option>
              <option value="MT" >MT</option>
              <option value="NC" >NC</option>
              <option value="ND" >ND</option>
              <option value="NE" >NE</option>

              <option value="NH" >NH</option>
              <option value="NJ" >NJ</option>
              <option value="NM" >NM</option>
              <option value="NV" >NV</option>
              <option value="NY" >NY</option>
              <option value="OH" >OH</option>

              <option value="OK" >OK</option>
              <option value="OR" >OR</option>
              <option value="PA" >PA</option>
              <option value="RI" >RI</option>
              <option value="SC" >SC</option>
              <option value="SD" >SD</option>

              <option value="TN" >TN</option>
              <option value="TX" >TX</option>
              <option value="UT" >UT</option>
              <option value="VA" >VA</option>
              <option value="VT" >VT</option>
              <option value="WA" >WA</option>

              <option value="WI" >WI</option>
              <option value="WV" >WV</option>
              <option value="WY" >WY</option>
              <option value="AA" >AA</option>
              <option value="AE" >AE</option>
              <option value="AP" >AP</option>

              <option value="AS" >AS</option>
              <option value="FM" >FM</option>
              <option value="GU" >GU</option>
              <option value="MP" >MP</option>
              <option value="MH" >MH</option>
              <option value="PR" >PR</option>

              <option value="PW" >PW</option>
              <option value="VI" >VI</option>
            </select></td>
   <td><span>*</span>Zip</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td><span>*</span>E-mail</td>
   <td colspan="5"><input name="email" id="email" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td><span>*</span>Phone Number</td>
   <td colspan="5">
       ( <input id="phone1" name="phone1" size="3" /> )
       <input id="phone2" name="phone2" size="3" /> -
       <input id="phone3" name="phone3" size="4" />
   </td>
</tr>

<tr><td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td colspan="5">Registration Fee</td>
   <td>$<input type="text" id="regFee" name="regFee" value="125.00" readOnly="true" />
</tr>

<tr>
   <td colspan="6">Optional (additional fees may apply)</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td colspan="5">
       <input type="checkbox" onchange="calcMeals()" name="opt1" id="optBreakfast" value="5" /> Breakfast ($5)
       <input type="checkbox" onchange="calcMeals()" name="opt2" id="optLunch" value="10" /> Lunch ($10)
       <input type="checkbox" onchange="calcMeals()" name="opt3" id="optHappyHour" checked value="0" /> Happy Hour (free!)
   </td>
   <td>$<input type="text" id="options" name="options" value="0.00" readOnly="true" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td colspan="2">Number attending dinner banquet ($30 per person)</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>
       <select id="guests" name="guests" onchange="CalcBanq()">
       <option>0</option>
       <option>1</option>
       <option>2</option>
       <option>3</option>
       <option>4</option>
       <option>5</option>
       </select>
   </td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>$<input type="text" id="banq" name="banq" value="0.00" readOnly="true" /></td>
</tr>

<tr><td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td colspan="5">Grand Total Due</td>
    <td>$<input type="text" id="grandTotal" name="grandTotal" readOnly="true" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

<p><span>* Required Information</span></p>
<p style="text-align: center"><input id="sbutton" type="submit" value="Register" onclick="return validateForm()" /></p>

</form>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    calcTotal();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to return true at the end and do everybody a favour and attach the handler to on submit instead of on click it is not recommended to touch the submit button. Lastly move the inline calc to onload of the page. Ps: it is obviously homework so try not to do all his work for him. The homework tag is deprecated for some unfathomable reason.